# Shortcut to Chrome DevTools via Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there an extension to open the chrome dev tools? I know there is a shortcut (clr+shift+c) but I would prefer to click on the extension icon to open the dev tools element inspector. I have searched a lot on the chrome web store and on stack but couldn't find any references to such an extension. Any help regarding this would be great.

Comment: Extensions can't do that. A few [whitelisted](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/_permission_features.json?l=225-235&rcl=23a6577c) Chrome [apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/) can use chrome.developerPrivate.inspect API. You can copypaste the [`"key"` from ADT's manifest](https://github.com/googlearchive/apps-developer-tools/blob/master/manifest.json) into your **local** chrome app (you won't be able to publish it) to be able to use this API. You can write an extension that invokes a separate utility via nativeMessaging API that sends the hotkey.

Comment: Is it possible for an extension to simulate the ctrl+shift+c behavior?

Comment: No, a browser's own UI can't be invoked by a synthetic keyboard event sent from JavaScript.

Comment: That was fast!! Thanks for the info